# Working with protocols - how to send a message back to the ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I subclassed `UIImageView` to add additional methods. I place this object on my `viewController` and I have a touch gesture recogniser up and running for that object. I have a few of those. My intention is that upon touch, something will happen in the `viewController` according to which of my subclasses `UIImageView`s got touched (can already distinguish between which of them has been touched).

I want to send a message (a property from the touched item) to the `viewController` so I can act accordingly. However, I failed to do that. I tried to implement a protocol for this purpose but it doesnt seem to work. I think my problem is about understanding how this works, since I get confused (how the delegate interacts with my touch recogniser?), and I fail to implement a working protocol successfully.

My `viewController` is called `EditViewController`. The subclass I made of `UIImageView` is called `ClickableImage` (I have my reasons :), which implements:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // some code calculating the index i want to return to the viewcontroller
}
```

How do I make this all work? How do I return that index to my `viewController`? Please give me a skeleton of an example so I can work with it, or explain how to, beacuse im clueless :)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you post the code for your protocol, we may be able to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: why would people downvote my post? i think its quite helpful for new people who handle this kind of issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, protocols and delegates are meant to allow you send message to another controller to execute an action.

In your `UIImageView` subcalss, the `ClickableImage.h`:

```
@class  ClickableImage;
@protocol ClickableImageDelegate<NSObject>

-(void)delegateMethod:(id)sender;//This method will be executed in EditViewController

@end

@interface ClickableImage : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong)id <ClickableImageDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

**ClickableImage.m:**

```
    //...
    @synthesize delegate;

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        // some code calculating the index i want to return to the viewcontroller
            id index;//initialize the index
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)]){
                 [self.delegate delegateMethod:index];
            }

    }
```

**EditViewController.h:**

```
@interface EditViewController : UIViewController<ClickableImageDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) ClickableImage *clickableImageController;
```

**EditViewController.m:**

```
     //....
     @synthesize clickableImageController;
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
        self.clickableImageController.delegate = self;//Don't forget to make a property for clickableImageController 

}
    -(void)delegateMethod:(id)sender{

    //sender is the index, Do your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - dont i need to synthesize the delegate? or set the delegate somewhere? i put some NSLog for testing at delegateMethod and it doesnt work

Comment: yes, you should synthesize the delegate, I edited my answer.

Comment: doesnt seem to work, i added the NSLog to your 'if' and it doesnt even get there

Comment: @Malloc: This code will (probably) lead to a retain cycle.  The `delegate` @property should be `weak`, not `strong`.

Comment: i think setting the delegate is required - he does not know if the delegate responds to the protocol or not. how do i do that?

Comment: Are you creating new instance of `ClickableImage` controller before calling the delegate method? edit your post and provide code of the way you are using so far.

Comment: @Zephyer yes, my bad, you should also set the delegate in `EditViewController`, I edited my post.

Comment: solved the problem - needed to set delegate as mentioned - thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to post a notification inside your touchesBegan:withEvent: 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification...

and to add an observer for this notification inside your controller